# Instagram API - Get number of likes without authentication token using media-id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, instagram-api

Here is the situation i am working on. In our application different users can log in to Instagram and upload the media. I have collection of all the media-id uploaded by different users.Now I want to get number of likes on each of the media uploaded. I read the documentation on instagram developer and i have few questions to clarify.

1. Is it really necessary to get authenticated in order to get number of likes on any media. ?
2. If yes then can i access number of likes on the media uploaded by other users ? OR API can only access the details of the account for which Token has been generated ?
3. Is it even possible to get the number of likes without generating authentication token using media-id ?

Platform is ASP.NET MVC. Please share your knowledge on this and point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[From Instagram's Changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/) as of Nov 17, 2015:

> All API endpoints require a valid access_token

You'll notice this on their [Like Endpoints documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/):

> Parameters access_token
>
> A valid access token.

Every API call regarding likes (and any endpoint for that matter) requires an access token

Comment: Thanks. I saw this. I am concerned that i do have lot of Media-id for which i need to get the number of likes. And also the big deal is i need to generate this access_token as and when expired without user intervention. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi would this help to answer your question completely? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22780703/4498937

Comment: thanks for your comment. Still i have 2 things to figure out. If token expires is there any possibility that aerver side code can generate new token  ? Another thing is api rate limit. Is there any way i can make as much calls as i need to api ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi you will do some research yourself. you need code that will check if the token you made the request with is valid; if it isn't, it will return an API error -> `error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError`. you can check this and renew your token if necessary server side. There are specific endpoint rate limits, but altogether it is 5000/hour in Live mode.