# Instagram API: getting users feed from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, authentication, instagram

I am trying to get the last couple of photos posted by a certain user.

On this site I've found many answers saying that it is possible to do that without an authentication token (for example, [How can I get a user's media from Instagram without authenticating as a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user/20529864#20529864)).

Whenever I open https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=cocacola&client_id=5c314c67157f4585ba3041281540c59b on my browser, I get a valid json response. But when I perform a get request on a javascript in my site, it fails.

EDIT: For future reference, the problem is related to cross domain requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jsonp, e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=cocacola&client_id=5c314c67157f4585ba3041281540c59b", 
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: How didn't I realize this.