# Instagram Media Endpoint Paging

Tags: json, instagram

I'm currently looking at reading out posts and related json data from a given number of Instagram users using the following URL:

https://www.instagram.com//media/

This will only bring back the latest 20 posts. I have done some hunting around and I am unable to see how to form the url to bring back the next 20 results. I've seen some places that have suggested using max_timestamp, but I can't see how to make this work.

For various reasons I do not wish to use the standard Instagram API.

Comment: What are you using for fetch data? i'm still looking for a library. this method remain the one for get public data without generate access_token for any account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `max_id` parameter to pagination.

Example: `https://www.instagram.com/[user-login]/media/?max_id=[last-min-id]`, where `[last-min-id]` is a minimal `id` from previous page. The `id` does not repeat in new page.

Answer (score 1):

This endpoint 'https://www.instagram.com/[user-login]/media/' is currently turned off in the last few days, unsure exactly when.

If you are dependant on it, you might want to check it now in your apps.

e.g. https://www.instagram.com/fosterandpartners/media/

Comment: I switched to using yet an another unofficial endpoint. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user/33783840#33783840)