# How to retrieve instagram photos with certain hashtag without using client_id or access_token

Tags: json, instagram, hashtag

I've built a website that show photos with certain hashtag while using client_id and access_token to call instagram API, and it work successfully.

Since my client is in Sandbox mode, I have to use someone else's client_id to call instagram API. I'm curious if there's any solution that can retrieve the search result of certain hashtag in JSON format without using client_id and access_token.

I've found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user) that can retrieve user photo feed in JSON format, but I can't find any solution that can retrieve the search result of certain hashtag in JSON format [like this](https://www.instagram.com/smena8m/media/). Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

These guys provide such service for everyone

[instagram.pixelunion.net](http://instagram.pixelunion.net/)

Basically, the site is not necessary, you can authorize yourself through API by calling:

[api](https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=1677ed07ddd54db0a70f14f9b1435579&redirect_uri=http://instagram.pixelunion.net&response_type=token)

If you learn someone's client_id, you can make token for yourself without their knowledge  or permission.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the photos from instagram by using this.

```
$hashtag = "fun";
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/".$hashtag."/?__a=1";
$res = @file_get_contents($url);
$media = json_decode($res, true);
$image = $media["tag"]["media"]["nodes"];
```

NOTE: I am not sure for if the API rules policy changes from Instagram in future.