# How can I display my Instagram posts (all) on my website

Tags: php, magento, instagram, instagram-api

I want to display all my instagram posts on my website. It only returns 20 posts at a time in sandbox mode. But my requirement is to show all my posts on my website.
When I try to submit my app for review it (Instagram API) shows me a my usecase in listed options which is:

> I want to display my Instagram posts on my website.

But when selected it shows this:

> You do not need to submit for review
>   for this use case. If you are a developer and you want to display
>   Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your
>   app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still
>   access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you
>   permission.

It doesn't show me any way to submit for review using this usecase and when I choose any other usecase my app gets rejected.

I resolved this issue by taking help from this comment last time but it seem to have stopped working after June 1, 2016:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529864

Comment: Did you try this extension https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html