# Is there still a way to fetch instagram feed without using access token now (06/2016)?

Tags: api, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I have an issue that my Instagram API access token keeps expiring frequently and I red the document and understood that although the token wouldn't expire generally, Instagram may decide to expire a token any time for any security reason or whatever reasons.

I know that when it expires, I need to set up an authentication process and request for a new token and all those of things. But the problem is that my app is just retrieving my own feeds to show on my own website, once the token expires it doesn't make sense to set up such a process, the only thing I can do is to manually retrieve and update the token in my code.

So I was wondering if there is still a way to get feeds without using access token as I am just pulling in my own feeds. Or is there any other way I can solve this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is that PHP project that uses Instagram inner API. It can do most functions the site can. It does not need an access token, it uses your username and password: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Answer (score 24, accepted):

EDIT : you can now get the json data of your profile simply with this link : https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1

---

If your profile is set to public mode you can fetch your data from json response just write:
https://www.instagram.com/YOURUSERNAME/media

example: https://www.instagram.com/bestcookingvideos/media

you can see json structure with : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Note: This page is not active  anymore : https://www.instagram.com/YOURUSERNAME/media

**2020.11.17**

As in the answer you can get the profile details with **12 recent post** via `https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1` but the problem is that this does not allowed to fetch media pagination. So for that you need to use

`https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables={"id":"15165085906","first":20,"after":null}`

Above route will return first 20 media of the relevant user who belongs to the id and when we need get next 20 we need to pass the `end_cursor` which is in initial call .

[image]

For more info ref [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user)

Comment: @Dimitrije Zoroski, Do you know how I can iterate to get more post? or if it's possible to ask for more than 20 posts?

Comment: @Carol Yes. you can! With link :
https://www.instagram.com/bestcookingvideos/media/?max_id=LastIdOfItem

Where LastIdOfItem is id of your last item in json text, id is something like this. "id":"1394603188540132178_3272768483".

Comment: Confirmed working as at 19/10/2017. Although I'm pretty sure this is not a supported API.

Comment: Was this feature just discontinued?

Answer (score 66):

`https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/media` stopped working today. You can use `https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1` instead.

Comment: Do you know how to get the next page using ?__a=1 method? There is page_info.end_cursor in the returned JSON, but it is unclear how to use it.

Comment: @VladimirLebedev use the max_id parameter, such as https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1&max_id=[Last id on previous call]

Comment: Is there any rate limit for this? and also it is returning only 12 posts each page, any idea how to increase the posts per page?

Comment: This is very interesting. Is there any description of all parameters and why is it working without API key? Or maybe info if it is intended to work so or it is just some glitch.

Comment: json schema of `https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1` has been changed

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1 Its no more accessible. is there anything else ?

Comment: Yeah, it seems they took it down after the Facebook analytica thing.

Comment: Since this URL "instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1" is no more working now.. Did you guys find any alternate solution?

Comment: @KarimHaddad if that fits you, there is a PHP library that connects via user/pass https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can use this PHP [library](https://github.com/pgrimaud/instagram-user-feed) in version 5 which uses scrapping to retrieve informations.

Answer (score 7):

**2021 Update**: Due to instagram latest changes, this is no longer a reliable solution.

**Original Answer**:

You can use this jquery library I developed:

https://github.com/BanNsS1/jquery.instagramFeed

No api token required

**Edit for the coments below:**

It's just jquery powered library that allows you to load the first 12 items of any public instagram profile.

**How it solves the problem?** Loading 1 to 12 last posts without requiring an access token/api key

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            $.instagramFeed({
                'username': 'instagram',
                'container': "#instagram-feed1",
                'display_profile': true,
                'display_biography': true,
                'display_gallery': true,
                'get_raw_json': false,
                'callback': null,
                'styling': true,
                'items': 8,
                'items_per_row': 4,
                'margin': 1 
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Want more? It will take 2 clicks and some scroll.

Comment: can we get our own feeds(stories from people we follow) using this method?

Comment: Not yet, I'll take a look soon

Comment: jquery.instagramFeed no longer works in 2021, infortunately.. if someone still needs Instagram feed on their website - take a look at https://github.com/restyler/inwidget-proxified as a server-side alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a small SaaS that makes this dead simple: https://behold.so - it handles all the messy stuff with the new Instagram API, and just gives you a URL to a feed of posts as JSON. Like this: https://feeds.behold.so/zFgp2Jbbk23Ovf1ZUOhq

Once you have your feed URL, the code becomes trivial:

```
fetch('https://feeds.behold.so/xN3J7TZ59jIdH6IOWQ4d')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(photos => {
    photos.forEach(({
      id,             // The post ID
      mediaUrl,       // The image source
      permalink,      // URL of the Instagram post
      caption,        // Post caption
      mediaType,      // 'IMAGE', 'VIDEO', or 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM'
      thumbnailUrl,   // Only returned for video posts
      timestamp,      // Post publish date,
      children        // An array of CAROUSEL_ALBUM children. Each with id, mediaUrl, mediaType and thumbnailUrl
    }) => {

      // Step 3. Make magic happen...
      
    });
  });
```

Apologies for the self-promotion, but the truth is there just isn't a simple way around this issue in 2022. Meta made things intentionally very difficult.

Comment: What proxies do you use?

Comment: No proxies, this isn't a scraper. It uses the (incredibly annoying) official APIs.

Comment: Good service but requires access token from the page owner which complicates things. It should be simple enough to build your own feed fetcher API using Instagram's private API.

Comment: You can definitely build your own. As with everything like this, it's all about cost/benefit given the value of your time and the size of a project. Instagram's two APIs come with some gotchas and are frankly a little buggy. Access tokens also require regular refreshing, so at minimum you need to set up a service/cron job that does that. Part of the value of something like Behold is that we handle those complexities behind the scenes. By no means is it the only way, however.

Comment: This is really nicely done. Thank you for sharing!