# Is there CURRENTLY anyway to fetch Instagram user media without authentication?

Tags: web-crawler, instagram

Until recently there were several ways to retrieve Instagram user media without the need for API authentication. But apparently, the website stopped all of them.

Some of the **old** methods:

- https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-id/media/recent/
- https://www.instagram.com/user-id/media
- https://www.instagram.com/user-id/?__a=1

And some **old** related questions are:

- [How can I get a user's media from Instagram without authenticating as a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user)
- [Is there still a way to fetch instagram feed without using access token now (06/2016)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875945/is-there-still-a-way-to-fetch-instagram-feed-without-using-access-token-now-06?rq=1)

I was able to retrieve the first twenty items by **crawling** the webpage of the user, but this is not a good or standard method especially when Instagram is not supporting it officially.

I was wondering If you know any method that **currently** works?

Comment: Check out this answer, it does not require any authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49906525/278840. However, for me its not feasible as it requires two separate requests: one to get the "rhx_gis" secret from the page's source code and another one to get the actual JSON data...

Comment: Check my latest working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/819764 I've updated my old method with new CORS proxy by Google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, Instagram stopped many of its APIs, including the ones that require authentication. It states in https://www.instagram.com/developer/:

> To continuously improve Instagram users' privacy and security, we are
> accelerating the deprecation of Instagram API Platform, making the
> following changes effective immediately.

Some links explaining the details and causes of these changes:

- https://www.programmableweb.com/news/instagram-has-effectively-killed-its-public-api/brief/2018/04/04
- https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/
- https://www.macrumors.com/2018/04/04/instagram-disables-third-party-app-apis/

Some unofficial crawling methods have been proposed in (suggested by @Louis B.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49906525/278840. You should take into consideration that these methods are being transformed each week. Therefore, I definitely prefer to use the private API.

**Update 2018**:

The old public API (without auth) is working again. We can access by adding `?__a=1` to the end of a profile url, like [this](https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/?__a=1):

```
https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/?__a=1
```

**Update June 2022**

The old API '?__a=1' has stopped working again. It seems to be due to an error. The page redirects to the login page as a guest. If you open it after logging in, it shows a weird error:

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1005648797}}},"lid":"7106751273377983967"}

**Update December 2023 (requires valid auth cookies)**

The following link **works** and returns json (both parameters are required)

```
https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/?__a=1&__d=dis
```

Comment: can you link to Instagram's "private" API? I wasn't aware such a thing existed.

Comment: @ReactingToAngularVues Start here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/
example: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: I don't believe that's a "private API". That's Instagram's now deprecated public API.

Comment: "A private API is an interface that opens parts of an organization’s backend data and application functionality for use by developers working within (or contractors working for) that organization." — again, with more emphasis, what you are linking to is Instagram's _deprecated_, _public_ API.

Comment: The private-ness/public-ness of an “API” is not determined by which data it can access, but by _who_ can access it. It doesn’t matter if the API can perform mass updates on entire user data, if it’s a publicly accessible, documented API, it’s called a “public API”. A private API is an internal or undocumented set of access points designed for the company who developed the API only.

Comment: Check my latest working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/819764 I've updated my old method with new CORS proxy by Google.

Comment: something happen with this method, after 300 requests pear day to that url , instagram block  you

Comment: Hi, does anyone know how to deal with the issue that the images returned from https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/?__a=1 is not loading due to CORS.

Comment: @KhushiRaval Did you find any way to deal with CORS issue?

Comment: @Caeculus - I have replaced mentioned API with Instagram basic display API with authentication to resolve issues and get proper data.

Refer - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

Comment: The latest solution works only if you are logged...

Comment: It looks like the December 2023 link is now broken :(

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter/dart this solution works for me:

```
String url = "https://www.instagram.com/";
String userName= "instaUserName";

var res = await http.get(
Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull(url + username + "/?__a=1&__d=dis"))); 
// adding /?__a=1&__d=dis at the end will return json data

var userProfileInfo = json.decode(res.body);
print(userProfileInfo  );
```

Comment: This solution only works if I'm a logged user... only for me?