# Workaround for new Instagram API restriction for tagged content

Tags: api, instagram

I built a module for my company's marketing team to fetch all the photos based on a hashtag. Such as `#nofilter`.

I was using the URL `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent` with no problems until Instagram decided to change their API authentication to OAuth.

I followed the new guidelines but my client is still in sandbox mode and the API call doesn't return anything anymore. All it returns is:

> {"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

It seems like I need to submit my application to be reviewed before going live. But this doesn't seem possible, based on what i found from their submission guideline below. Is there any workaround for this?

[image: Permissions Review]

**====== UPDATE July 8th, 2016**

I have found one of those 3rd parties that instagram mentioned, but the pricing is awful https://www.dialogfeed.com/pricing/

189 euros per month seem a bit steep

Comment: It looks like they have decided to assert control over their content (even if that content is coming from their users) and not allow the wholesale grabbing of images anymore. What you are trying to do looks like it may bump up against any number of their [platform policies](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to deal with this.  Their documentation is pretty unhelpful and doesn't seem to offer any solution for someone just wanting to collect relevant links, which should be no prob.

Fortunately, the script on an Instagram page provides easy access to their structured data.  In my rails app I create a headless browser and just hit their url.  I provided my solution as an answer to another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572893/4888422

Comment: That looks cool, i hope there could be a better way than backdoor hacks soon