# How to use Instagram API for static, single page app?

Tags: javascript, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am building a static, client-side only website for a client. I'd like to display recent instagram posts that use their hash tag.

However, all calls to the Instagram API need an access_token. This use case is different, though, bc I'm not trying to ask the user to authenticate their account through OAuth, I'm only trying to use a static API call to show recent posts.

How can I do this?

EDIT: 
This is not a duplicate of the other because Instagram's API has been updated to require an `access_token` for all endpoints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a user's media from Instagram without authenticating as a user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user)

Comment: Thanks, @MikeC. Please see edit above. :-)

Comment: According to the Instagram API (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/), you must include an access token when requesting media. It would seem that you'll need a server to give your client an Instagram access token, so it does not look like you can do this client-side only.

Answer (score 1):

Use Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication, this does not require server-side code, can be done all in javascript single page app to get `access_token`

Here is details:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: The use case of this is not for the client to login, but to display my own feed or a hashtags feed to the user. Implicit flow would require the user to login.

Comment: u cannot access API without login, u have to login once, get access_token, store and use it for app