# Instagram media endpoint without authentication - https://www.instagram.com/${user}/media/ - unofficial?

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram introduced an obligatory authentication for their api https://api.instagram.com/v1/.

But it is still possible to get a public feed which is sufficient for my purpose https://www.instagram.com/${user}/media/ e.g.
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/media/.

I can't find this in the official documentation, though so that I'm hesitating to use it. Is this an unofficial api?

I found many sources using it and also many threads.Anyone found this in an instagram documentation?

Comment: Wow! This is #EPIC. I didn't know this existed. End of the feed has a `"more_available": true`  field. Any idea how to paginate using this?

Comment: I haven't tried but look at the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user/33783840#33783840

Comment: Its not official API, may stop working at some point, you can use it as long as it works.

Comment: @krisrak How do you know? Have you seen anything on this that I could show my colleagues?

Comment: There were other param like `max_tag_id` that i used to decode and do date/time search, which got changed two times and stopped working, you just cant rely on it if it is not officially documented. I do use the unofficial API mentioned above in http://gramfeed.com, since it is an old app which is transitioned to https://picodash.com now and just used to redirect. picodash uses official API and requires login, gramfeed uses unofficial API no login, but is just used to redirect it to picodash

Comment: Instagram seems to have changed this recently, urls like https://www.instagram.com/instagram/media/ do not work anymore.