# From Instagram : how to display multiple user's hastags all photos on our website

Tags: instagram

Previously, Instagram allow to fetch all the photos based on a hashtag and display to our website. e.g #mytag

url : https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent with no problems until Instagram decided to change their API authentication to OAuth.

but now we can't get all photos related to hashtag. only user can get his own instagram hashtag photos.

so please advice any one have any idea. how can we get all photos related to  hashtags and show to our website.

I need all photos based on same hashtag given by diff diff user. also when i try to get info use of this url `api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]`

It gives me below reply:

> {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is
>   invalid.", "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException"}}

Their submission guideline is like this:

[image]

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a user's media from Instagram without authenticating as a user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user)