# Is it possible to embed another user's instagram feed on my website?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'd like to display some photos from an instagram account that I have no connection to on my website, is this possible/allowed?

(In actual fact I'd like to do it for 200+ different accounts, none of which I'm directly affiliated with)

Comment: But I'm not asking about my own photos, I'm asking if it's possible to do others' photos.

Comment: Still same API. Refere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user).