# Getting the followers count of an Instagram profile without an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, instagram

After a lot of Googling I just can't seem to find an updated way of getting the follower count of an Instagram account. I want it displayed on my personal website so I probably need to use JavaScript and jQuery.

I already figured out how to get a YouTube sub count, but I can use the YouTube API.

Does anyone have a way of doing this without an API? I know there are probably some other ways, but I'm definitely not experienced enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Without using the instagram API, there is no easy* way to do so, no.**

If you are not opposed to using the instagram API, however do not want to require the user to log in, this [SO question may be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user).

Comment: Note that some public endpoints of the Instagram API have recently been removed. You will likely no longer be able to access follower data for unauthorized users. See [Platform Changelog - Dec 11, 2018](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/#dec-11-2018)