# Instagram Basic Display - How do I get USER ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have the Instagram basic Display api set up and working ok to get my data. However if I try to get a user data (not mine), non of the ids work.

Here is how am searching in python code but its failing:

```
media = instagram_basic_display.get_user_media(user_id='nnnnn')
```

If I insert the user is from the url, it doesn't work.

What is the correct user_id to use in the above code in place of 'nnnnn'?

Comment: Have you seen a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805060/getting-user-media-with-instagram-basic-display-api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Basic Display API overview it says:

> The API can be used to access any type of Instagram account but only
> provides read-access to basic data. If you are building an app that
> will allow Instagram Businesses or Creators to publish media, moderate
> comments, identify @mentioned and hashtagged media, or get data about
> other Instagram users, use the Instagram Graph API instead.

So you may need to look into [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) instead.

Here are a couple great resources:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-instagram-posts-with-python-and-instagram-graph-api-374f084b9f2b
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8i4CaELPME
- https://github.com/imakashsahu/Instagram-Graph-API-Python

[Instabot](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/824) is also a terrific library.
To install it, simply run `pip install instabot`.
To get the users id and username, you can do this:

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()

user_id = bot.get_user_id_from_username("yourusername")
username = bot.get_username_from_user_id(user_id)
print(f"Welcome {username} your userid is {user_id}")
```

In conclusion, you cannot currently use Basic Display API to access a user name or id. Instead, you can use Instagram Graph API, or a useful instabot library.

Comment: The video in the answer gave me all the information I needed. Great video btw. Thanks. All up and running now :)

Comment: So the Graph api works but only against your own account. You cannot use it to view other accounts as you would normally do on a browser?