# Is it no longer possible to pull another user's photos/posts from Instagram using the Basic Display API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've been given a coding challenge as part of a job interview. I need to make an iOS app that shows the last ten Instagram posts from a user of my choosing. I've learned that Instagram's API changed last month, and from what I've researched so far it looks like it's now only possible to get posts of which that user has permission to, meaning you can't just pull anyone's Instagram's posts anymore. Can anyone confirm if this is true or not, and help find a possible solution?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer for this too because seems like you can't query another user save from the connected instagram user in which the `access_token` belong to.

Comment: Found this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/6143656